# Block website with HTTPS?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, https, apache-2.4

I hope my question is on topic on Server Fault. If not, please excuse me and point me into the right direction.

Is it possible to block a site with HTTPS?

I have a website that I would like to make accessible only to myself. Of course I could solve this programatically within the system, but I was asking myself whether it was possible to force HTTPS on port 443 for asking for a certain certificate and if not provided, then return some kind of 404 error or similar. So in other words I need to have the appropriate certificate on my client system in order to be able to access the site.

Is that generally possible? If yes, could someone point me to a documentation on that? Maybe for Apache if existent?

Comment: Client certificates?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_howto.html#accesscontrol

Comment: Yes, client certificates. And only if the client has the certificate installed, only then he will be able to see the page. If does not have the certificate, there will be absolutely no possibility for him to view the page.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Yep it is possible.

[Here](http://www.garex.net/apache/) is a good tutorial.

But another, simpler way of doing this would be with a [.htaccess file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/howto/htaccess.html).

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! We really do prefer that answers contain content not pointers to content. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: If you were to summarize the tutorial or provide a brief how-to, to go along with the links, this would actually be a very good answer, but as it stands now, it's just a couple of links, and link-only answers are discouraged at Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thank you @Loïc Basset ! Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late answer, but seeing as you tagged the question with Apache-2.4 this is a native part of the Apache HTTP Server:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html#accesscontrol